# Rewrite $P(\mathrm{e}^X < 2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This might sound really simple, but how do I rewrite $P(\mathrm{e}^x < 2)$ so that it is only $x$ on the left side?

For example, I know that $P(x^2 < 1/2)$ would become $P(x < \sqrt{1/2})$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what logarithms are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take log both sides you would end up with
$$P(e^x <2)=P(x <ln2)$$.the inequality remains the same because $ln$ is a increasing for these values.taking $log$ is meaningful because $e^x>0$

Answer (score 0):

Your other statement in your question is false. "$x^2 < \frac{1}{2}$" is **NOT** equivalent to "$x < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$". In general given two **equivalent** sentences $A,B$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(B)$.